# inverse Laplace transform of rational function of Euler gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, fractional-calculus, inverse-laplace

***How do I calculate the inverse Laplace transform of the gamma function? I'd appreciate it if someone can help me.***
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{a s^{\alpha}}\frac{Γ(b+a s^{\alpha})}{Γ(b+a s^{\alpha}-n)}$$
I visited most of the books on Laplace's Transformation, but I am looking for a reference to explain completely about
Laplace inverse of the gamma function. Can anyone give me some info on this topic?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the parameters $a,b,c,\alpha$ and the branch of $s\mapsto s^{a}$ you are choosing?

Comment: The alpha parameter is a real number; in fact, the alpha is the fractional derivative parameter. After the work has been done and Laplace transforms into this, we must now apply Laplace's inverse. Indeed,  this parameter  in the fractional equations, Laplace transformation occurs. $a=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{m\pi}{A}},b=B \sqrt{\frac{2 m}{B}}$ A and B are Constants.

Comment: No one can answer my question, or even give guidance or introduce a reference?

Comment: Can someone introduce me a good reference to calculating Laplace's inverse transform of the gamma function? Mr. Ron Gordon, can you help me?